# Eventlistener not always called for jquery ui icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

as UI Font I load this

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="/javascripts/jquery-ui-iconfont-master/jquery-ui.icon-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

in the page that is used for a player

```
<div id="iconStop" class="ui-icon ui-icon-stop">icon</div>
<div id="iconRecord" class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-on">icon</div>
<div id="iconPause" class="ui-icon ui-icon-pause">icon</div>
```

than that

```
function sendCommand(name){
      sendJson('mode:'+name);
 }
 window.onload = function () {
       document.getElementById("iconStop").addEventListener("click",function(){ sendCommand('stop'); } );
       document.getElementById("iconRecord").addEventListener("click",function(){ sendCommand('record'); } );
       document.getElementById("iconPause").addEventListener("click",function(){ sendCommand('pause'); } );
   }
```

the odd thing is that a click only works sometimes. A manual call of sendCommand('any') works all the time ! 
Any idea why that is not always working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the fix was simple by changing the event to mousedown like that

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("iconStop").addEventListener("mousedown",function(){ sendCommand('stop'); } );
    document.getElementById("iconRecord").addEventListener("mousedown",function(){ sendCommand('record'); } );
    document.getElementById("iconPause").addEventListener("mousedown",function(){ sendCommand('pause'); } );
}
```

at least for firefox and chrome this works much better

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is tricky thing with loading jquery and using pure javascript for handling events. In your case I recommend something like this:

```
function sendCommand(name){
    sendJson('mode:'+name);
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#iconStop').on('click', function() { sendCommand('stop'); } );
    OR
    $('#iconStop').click(function() { sendCommand('stop'); } );
})
```

The main difference here is, there will be page ready and jquery too. And my code using jquery listeners, so there shouldn't be case where listeners collide with each other.

Comment: thanks for that. unfortunately same result. When reducing to only one icon it works nicely. Therefore I think this is an odd bug in the fonts library